# Output a text file including the command that was used to generate it

Tags: linux, pipe

Surely there must be a more elegant way to do this! I would like to execute a command and then create a text file with the command itself, a couple of new lines, and then the output of the command.

For context, the reason for doing this is so that a person who views the text file will be able to see the command which is necessary to refresh the file's contents.

Here's an example which gives nearly the correct result, but is cumbersome.

```
cat /proc/meminfo > meminfo.txt; sed -i '1s/^/\/proc\/meminfo pipeSymbol meminfo\.txt \n\n/' meminfo.txt
```

Here are the contents of the `meminfo.txt` file:

```
/proc/meminfo pipeSymbol meminfo.txt

MemTotal:       263024768 kB
MemFree:        255517652 kB
```

I'd like to improve it in the following ways if possible. But anything to make it a bit cleaner would also be appreciated.

- Remove the need to write the command again manually
- Remove the need to manually escape special symbols in the `sed` command
- In case the above cannot be accomplished, how can I insert `>` instead of the text `pipeSymbol`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another symbol as separator in sed. You could write your set statement like below.

```
cat /proc/meminfo > meminfo.txt; sed -i '1s#^#/proc/meminfo >  meminfo.txt \n\n#' meminfo.txt
```

You could do it like below. First set your command and output to variables. And execute them as variables.

```
mycmd="ls -l"
out="myout.txt"
eval $mycmd > $out; sed -i -e "1s#^#$mycmd > $out \n\n#" $out
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a big improvement. Could you however help me resolve this error?

`$ mycmd="ls -l"; out="myout.txt"; eval $mycmd > $out; sed -i "1s#^#$mycmd >  $out \n\n#" $out`

`sed: 1: "myout.txt": invalid command code m`

Comment: Perhaps you should prefix sed expression with -e like this ```mycmd="ls -l"; out="myout.txt"; eval $mycmd > $out; sed -i -e "1s#^#$mycmd > $out \n\n#" $out```

Comment: should be ok but I need to test it still. Thanks for checking. I’ll mark it answered soon.